# How can i create borders to an entire circuit/track?

Tags: modeling, extrude

i'm making a highway based on a reference, and right now is working as a plane, but i need to make 'borders' for it, how can i make them? if i select all the edges, *i can extrude them, but they still appear as planes*, after that, how can i give them volume? or is there any other way to do it?

This is the highway i'm making, is a solid mesh, based on curves, but is still a plane (as you can see on the image of the right)

[image]

And this is what i want to achieve, those 'borders/blocks' around the edges of the highway itself.

[image]

Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the edges, extrude them and then you will have flat faces as borders. Select those faces (with face select mode) and extrude them upwards. You can extrude faces just like you can extrude vertices and lines.

Comment: But will i have to do them separately, one by one? i mean, i can extrude all of them in one shorcut, but what i need is something similar because i want them to have the same dimensions.
Do i need to extrude the borders with S? (Scale)

Comment: Select all the faces together, with shift-Right click and then hit E to extrude. After you hit E, you can use the mouse to place the extrusion and click the Left mouse button.